How do I use the date the picker gives me after I change the date?
I can't get the value from the Picker so I can use it in my next class. I was trying to run the Picker class on GitHub to observe different pickers, but there is so much code from the spinner family that does not work. So back to my original code. I need to know what I am missing in the example to end the dialog after the Done button is pressed in the picker. Here is the code:
            if (nplans == null) {
                    Dialog dlg = new Dialog("");
                    Picker datePicker = new Picker();
                    datePicker.setUseLightweightPopup(true);
                    String wdate = new Date().toString();
                    datePicker.setDate(new Date());
                    dlg.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    dlg.addComponent(CENTER, datePicker);
                    selectedDate = datePicker.getValue().toString();//Text();

                    dlg.showPacked(CENTER, true);
                    dlg.setDisposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds(true);
                    Dialog.show("Selected Date", selectedDate, "OK", null);
            } else {
                    new Plan();
            }
        } catch(IOException err) {
            Log.e(err);
        }


You're relying on some EDT gymnastics here that could fail in very weird ways.
The first dialog stops the EDT and holds input which might release the dialog and might not. Generally I would advise against putting input within a dialog, especially a picker since a picker might behave differently on every OS.
I would suggest putting the picker directly in your form and using the action listener to track changes to the picker value asynchronously. That is the right cross platform way to accomplish that.

Thanks, Shai. I am checking for null to open the dialog, so instead I will incorporate a picker window to choose the first date for the database.
